# Dm everyone who has a role discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna dm everyone who has the `dmme` role using `on_ready` (dm updates system)
But i can't get it to work. I know that this code is outdated, but i've never done anything like this before and I don't know how to.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, message = "test"):
    print("ready")
    if member == "@dmme":
        for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
            await bot.send_message(server_member, message)
```

[How to DM everyone with a bot - discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785727/how-to-dm-everyone-with-a-bot-discord-py)

[How to DM everyone in a Discord server with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813895/how-to-dm-everyone-in-a-discord-server-with-discord-py)

Also..how can i make it only select `x` users with the role and dm only them (insider program with random testing selection)

Answer (score 3):

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:  # all servers of the bot
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'dmme ', guild.roles)
        for member in guild.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.send("WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SAY")
```

But:

1. Make sure you enable intents for that.
2. It‘s not a good idea to dm many people at the same time because of a limit for that from discord. So think twice if you really want to do that. (My bot got blocked for one hour because of similar stuff)

Comment: Given the second warning I realised that I 100% need the random selection of a given number of users.. There isn't really a way to do that, right ?

Comment: `guild.members` is a list. So you could use the `random` module with its `random.choices()` method in order to select a random amount of people.

Comment: what if you have a random timeout after each message? do you still hit the limits?like a sleep 10 added insdie your for loop